# R Shiny Speed Up Data Loading

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny app that requires to load a .RData file first. The .RData file has only one big file that has 28 millions rows with 25 variables. The Shiny page takes more than 2 mins to show up because the file is big. Our acceptable loading time is within 30s. Is anyone have any suggestions of how to speed up the loading?

I did try to load the data by fread function (from data.table pkg) but it still takes 2mins+ to load. I guess load(.RData) is still faster than fread(.csv)?

Thank you!

Comment: do you really need to download that many? Could you just summarise/aggregate before uploading?

Comment: @MLavoie Unfortunately, I have to, because the Shiny page is to enable people to explore what kinds of data we have. However, the file is big because I merged and melt several data files together. Maybe I could upload them and do the transformation on the server.

Comment: You aren't going to get much faster than `fread`, except maybe `readRDS` (and that's just a guess). I really doubt you need to have all that data in memory to just "explore" it. You could put it in a db and have actions in the shiny app pull only the pieces it needs.

Comment: I am not sure Shiny is good to explore data if you 28 millions rows :-)

Comment: You can delay load the whole dataset by only loading data you need to configure the process (categories, field names, ...) that could be provided as a separate data structure. The UI will also load faster

Answer (score 2):

Don't use compression - if you have fast disk and the variables are numerical then using uncompressed RDS is much faster than compressed:

```
> l = lapply(1:25, function(o) rnorm(28e6))
> names(l) = paste0("V",1:25)
> attr(l,"row.names") = .set_row_names(length(l[[1]]))
> class(l) = "data.frame"
> saveRDS(l, file="data.rds", compress=FALSE)
```

(new session)

```
> system.time(d<-readRDS("data.rds"))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.474   2.091   8.576 
> dim(d)
[1] 28000000       25
```

That said, this seems like a good use case for [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) where you can pre-load data so when the user connects the data is already loaded and shared by all sessions (assuming you're not running a Windows server).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try your suggestion but it still took 60+ seconds. I guess because the file contains multiple data types (numeric, char, date). Eventually I end up import several small pieces and then merge them together by using data.table package. It has allow.cartesian=TRUE so the file becomes bigger but it is fast. I was able to reduce speed down to 15 seconds.